# Error ‘Your config file does not appear to be formatted correctly.’ message in Codeigniter3

Tags: codeigniter

I am just restart my Webserver(nginx) then try my website

I get a error called `Your config file does not appear to be formatted correctly.` What is mean?

Comment: Look carefully at the file application/config/config.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about your configuration of CI. but i faced same problem while updating wrong configuration as @cartalot.

and my changes was

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";
$config['base_url_https'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";
```

and i change it to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";
$config['base_url_https'] = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";
```